# message to show hide a window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

is there a message that I can send to a window that will have the same effect as `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` or `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a message that I can send to a window that will have the same effect as `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)` or `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`?

No.

Answer (score 1):

```
::SetWindowPos( window_handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ( visible ? SWP_SHOWWINDOW : SWP_HIDEWINDOW ) | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try [WM_SHOWWINDOW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632645%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

I'm not 100% sure if it will actually show/hide a window when posted, or whether it's only an "informative" hint to the application that this is happening, but it's worth a try.

Comment: this is a notification message sent to the windows to inform them of a change in showing state.